# Module build failed - no ESLint configuration found after import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, eslint, vue-cli

I have worked on a vue project which I created using vue cli. Because of this, eslint is also included in the project. Up until now I haven't done much with eslint. If I understood correctly, eslint helps with stylistic errors, semantic errors etc in the code to identify potential problems.
I only rarely used `// eslint-disable-next-line` if there was e.g. a console.log clashing with the rules.

Now I wanted to include some new javascript code into the project. This code comes from someone else, so I cloned the repo and then just imported it in my **main.js** via a relative path to the folder/file that I have cloned. I think this was okay. However now I get some problems with eslint as the imported file has no config for eslint.
This is the exact error originating from the import:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
Error: No ESLint configuration found
```

I am not sure what to do now, even though I already searched for the error. 
I only saw some config for eslint in the package.json, I think. If it would help to have its content or something else, please say so and I will add it!

How can I tackle this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but this is the .eslintrc.js file I shove into all my react projects at the root directory to get rid of that error. You'll want to change some of the settings but this is the basic structure.

```
module.exports = {
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['react', 'react-hooks'],
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    'plugin:json/recommended',
    'prettier',
  ],
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
  rules: {
    'react/prop-types': ['off'],
    'react/no-unescaped-entities': ['error', { forbid: ['>', '}'] }],
  },
};
```